# How to use NSUserDefaults to store a row property

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a tab bar based application, with a `TableViewController` on a tab.

When i update my app, i add a new row to my `Table`.

What i want to do is store the highlight color of a row of my `TableViewController` as soon as i insert a new one, for at least 3 sessions.

I know that i have to use `NSUserDefaults`, but, where? 
I mean: should i use it into my `rowViewController` (which is a `UIViewController`) or into my `TableViewController`(where i have all the rows)?

And how can i import a cell property into the `UIViewController`(if is in there that i have to use the `NSUserDefaults`)?

i have something like:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*) notice {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:cell];
    if ([(NSInteger*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:cell] intValue] < 3) { 
        // render highlighted...
    } else {
        // render normal
    } }
```

I can't do it 'cause it's a UIViewController, right? Then in the .h at

```
@interface rowViewController : UIViewController
```

should i add something in order to implement the cell and then to set its properties (color)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't clear to me why you need to use NSUserDefaults for this. Is it always the same color? Do you need to store the color between app sessions?

Comment: I need to use the NSUserDefaults in order that when i add a new row with a background color (yellow, for example), it keeps being yellow for 3 sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the way you did in your question, but there is a big problem in your code. You use NSInteger like if it was an object, whereas it is an atomic type.

Don't confuse `NSInteger` and `NSNumber`:

- `NSNumber` is a class that aims to encapsulate numbers in an Objective-C object so that you can use it where `NSObjects` are requested (like when you want to store them in `NSDictionaries`)
- `NSInteger` is an alias (typedef) for an integer type. Use it the same way you would use an `int`.

So in your code, `NSUserDefaults`'s `setInteger:forKey:` and `integerForKey:` uses NSInteger values (namely atomic values, not objects). No need to use `*` and `intValue` then to retrieve the real value, you already have it! (The code like you wrote it will surely crash, interpreting an integer value as a pointer to a memory address!)

---

**Moreover, you can't use the cell as the key** of your `NSUserDefaults`. `NSUserDefaults` **only accept strings for the keys**, and moreover `UITableViewCells` are reused (recycled each time you scroll) and not persistant. You should instead build a string that uses the `NSIndexPath` of your cell and use it for your `NSUserDefaults` key; then store the background color of a cell/row at a given position in the `UITableView` (and anyway that's better separation of the Model and the View in the MVC design pattern).

```
// Build a string from the IndexPath that will be used as a unique key for your userdefaults, to store info on the corresponding row in your tableview
NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bkg_%i:%i",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:key];
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:key] < 3)
{ 
    // render highlighted...
} else {
    // render normal
}
```

---

Note that `integerForKey:` can be seen as a call to `objectForKey:` (that will return an `NSObject`, typically an `NSNumber` in your case, which is an object encapsulating the integer value) followed by a call to `integerValue`.

```
// These lines...
NSNumber* nbrObj = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mykey"];
NSInteger nbr = [nbrObj integerValue];
// are equivalent to the following, shorter line:
NSInteger nbr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"mykey"];
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to make something out

Comment: You can use the `NSUserDefaults` directly in your class that implements the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol (typically your `UITableViewController`). No need to "import" your cell into your UIViewController (that doesn't really mean anything actually). Do read the "Table View Programming Guide" in Apple documentation, it will help you understand the mechanisms of `UITableViews` in depth, including the layout/display cycle and the reuse mechanism (the fact that cells are reused/recycled).

Comment: Also read documentation about the MVC design pattern, it will help you understand how you should split info from the "display" and infos related to the "model" and metadata. PS: I edited my answer to add some sample code

Comment: Relying on the -description method in your code is really not recommended. It's intended more as a debugging aid than as a serialization or unique identifier method.

Comment: Looool I **totally** agree with you, and that's a shame I did this because I'm the first to tell others (even here on SO) to avoid using `description` for anything else than debugging !! ;) Will edit this right now, thx